# How to search element in array with arrays

Tags: php

What is the best way to search element in this array?

```
    $emailsArray= array(
            'http://gmail.com' => 'gmail.com',
            'http://poczta.onet.pl' => array('onet.pl','vp.pl', 'op.pl', 'spoko.pl', 'poczta.onet.pl', 'onet.eu', 'onet.com.pl', 'opoczta.pl','autograf.pl','vip.pl','vip.onet.pl'),
            'http://poczta.wp.pl' => 'wp.pl',
            'http://poczta.o2.pl' => 'o2.pl',
            'http://mail.tlen.pl' => 'tlen.pl',
            'http://poczta.interia.pl' => array('interia.pl','poczta.fm','interia.eu'),
            'http://poczta.gazeta.pl' => 'gazeta.pl',
            'http://pl.mail.yahoo.com' => array('yahoo.pl','yahoo.com'),            
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what you are searching for you could do something along these lines:

```
$emailDomain = 'o2.pl'; //grab this from an email you want to check

$emailsArray= array(
            'http://gmail.com' => 'gmail.com',
            'http://poczta.onet.pl' => array('onet.pl','vp.pl', 'op.pl', 'spoko.pl', 'poczta.onet.pl', 'onet.eu', 'onet.com.pl', 'opoczta.pl','autograf.pl','vip.pl','vip.onet.pl'),
            'http://poczta.wp.pl' => 'wp.pl',
            'http://poczta.o2.pl' => 'o2.pl',
            'http://mail.tlen.pl' => 'tlen.pl',
            'http://poczta.interia.pl' => array('interia.pl','poczta.fm','interia.eu'),
            'http://poczta.gazeta.pl' => 'gazeta.pl',
            'http://pl.mail.yahoo.com' => array('yahoo.pl','yahoo.com'),            
    );


foreach ($emailsArray as $host => $domains) {
    if (is_string($domains)) {
        $domains = array($domains);
    }

    if (in_array($emailDomain, $domains)) {
        echo "The email is hosted at $host\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a foreach  as $key => $value, within that an if is_array ($value) foreach $value as $key => $val

Then just check for matches within those loops